# WSO2-IS 5.10.0 - IDTokenIssuerID - deployment.toml

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am setting up an identity provider on WSO2 AM to use the tokens generated by WSO2 IS and, as far as I know, it needs to have the same name as IDTokenIssuerID. In old versions I usually changed the value of IDTokenIssuerID in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`.

How can I change using deployment.toml in newer version?

I'm running everything on docker environment and if I change the value in identity.xml, in volume, it is overwritten when docker starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this in deployment.toml:

```
[oauth.oidc]
id_token.issuer = "ID_NAME"
```